# Configure IE to use a SOCKS5 proxy instead of SOCKS4

Tags: proxy, internet-explorer-9, socks5

When configuring IE to use a SOCKS proxy server it does not allow you to
specify what version of SOCKS should be used. I would like IE to initiate
the handshake using SOCKS version 5, not SOCKS version 4. Is this possible?
Does IE 9 support the use of SOCKS version 5?

Comment: Internet Explorer 9 does not support SOCKS5.

Comment: @iglvzx does any version support socks5. Also chrome uses default system settings. Than it doesn't support socks5 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE does not support SOCKS5.

[FreeCap](http://www.freecap.ru/eng/) adds very granular selective SOCKS support.

Comment: does this still hold true with IE 11 and edge? what versions of Socks does it support?

Comment: still true, SOCKS4 only